# Getting warnings on my Kotlin versions while building app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

i'm learning programming android app with kotlin language. It's my first time i'm using kotlin and i have warnings that i don't understand when i'm building the app.

Here are the warnings

[image]

Dependencies :

[image]

Build.gradle file (Project)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading `kotlin_version` to `1.5.10` inside the `gradle file(project)`

Here is the snapshot

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first option is to upgrade to a newer version of gradle. Second, try to update the jdk